# Setting up PowerBI email subscription thows an error: "Something went wrong"

Tags: powerbi

When I try setting up a subscription to a PowerBI report I get an error "Something went wrong".

I have tried all combinations of options on the subscription, daily, weekly, different times, filling in every field etc but still no joy.

I have raised a support ticket with Microsoft but whilst I wait for a reply, has anyone had this before and solved it?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out Microsoft support is on the ball today, I have an answer.

In PowerBI Service, go to:

Gear Cog -> Settings -> Language and select your language. Turn out the default "Browser Language" setting causes this error to be displayed.

My subscriptions are now set up! :)

[image]